# Dynamically remove Characters from Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea which will have a **dynamic maxlength, depending on the Dropdown**.

I have a situation in which,
If the User chooses to **select an option with longer maxlength ie. "b"** in by case,
Then types in characters 
**and later 

chooses an option with shorter maxlength, ie. "a" in my case** 
I need to **remove the extra number of characters from the textarea, typed in when longer option from dropdown was selected**.

Here's a sample code:

```js
var maxLen;

function lengthChange() {
  var id = $('#ta').attr("id");
  var dropdown = $('#choice').val();
  var taValue = $('#ta').val();
  var len = taValue.length;
  if (dropdown == "a") {
    maxLen = "5";
    $('#' + id).attr("maxlength", maxLen);
  } else {
    maxLen = "10";
    $('#' + id).attr("maxlength", maxLen);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choice" name="choice" onchange="lengthChange()">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<textarea id="ta" name="ta" rows="4" cols="20" maxlength="5">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var maxLen;

function lengthChange()
{
    var $ta = $('#ta'),
        dropdown = $('#choice').val(),
        taValue = $ta.val();

    maxLen = dropdown === 'a' ? 5 : 10;
    $ta
        .attr('maxlength', maxLen)
        .val(taValue.substr(0, maxLen));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choice" name="choice" onchange="lengthChange()">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<textarea id="ta" name="ta" rows="4" cols="20" maxlength="5">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add to the bottom of your lengthChange() function something like this:

```
// Grab current textarea value
var text = $('#'+id).val();  
// Set textarea value to substring of up to length maxLen
$('#'+id).val(text.substr(0, maxLen));
```

This solution will work no matter what number maxLen happens to be, even if the contents of the textarea are shorter than maxLen.

Comment: The text is already defined at: `var taValue = $('#ta').val();`

Comment: @DaniP, I had envisioned placing my lines below the if/else block. That way more than two lengths can be accommodated and whatever maxLen happens to be after considering all possible dropdown values, it will be accommodated.

Comment: @YosvelQuintero, yes, and there are many other inefficiencies in the OP's code. But since I suggested adding my snippet at the very bottom of the function block, it gives the OP flexibility to make other changes in his function, after which `taValue` might be outdated, and still rely on what I put there. Your point is understood though.